# Paired test with 2 dependent variables

Tags: multiple-regression, predictor, intervention-analysis, mancova

What test should I use to find out what effect an intervention has on two dependent variables? I have a test group of clinically depressed that will undergo a sports program. The program is expected improve both physical as physiological trait. Also, I'm assuming that there is a correlation or covariance between physical and physiological. To put it simple: people who are more fit would be more happy, and people who are more happy are more fit.

I firstly thought about mancova because it measures the covariance between two dependent variables, but one of the assumptions is that the groups (time A and time B) are independent. Also multiple regression doesn't sound right because the independent variable is categorical. Any ideas?

*Time A*
(fitness & mood)

INTERVENTION fitness

*Time B*
(fitness & mood)